# No resource method found for PUT, return 405 with Allow header

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the reason for this error: 'No resource method found for PUT, return 405 with Allow header' and how can I fix it. while searching for the solution I find somewhere that I should add 'X-HTTP-Method-Override'in headers, I also did it but still facing same issue. I am sending put request to keycloak to update user data, Get request is working fine but PUT is giving me the error.

```
def update_user(user_id, user_data):
    import requests
    headers = dict()
    headers['X-HTTP-Method-Override'] = 'PUT'
    headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    data = {
        "grant_type": "password",
        "username": "admin",
        "password": os.getenv("KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_KEY"),
        "client_id": "admin-cli"
    }
    token = _request("POST", f"{server_internal_url}realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token", None, data=data).json()["access_token"]
    # token = admin_token()
    headers["Authorization"] = f"Bearer {token}"
    headers["Host"] = kc_host
    # here = _request("PUT", admin_url+f"/users"+"/".format(user_id=user_id), token, data=json.dumps(user_data)).json()

    response = requests.put(admin_url + "/users/" + user_id, headers=headers, data=data, verify=VERIFY)
    print(response.json())
```

Comment: You are trying tp `PUT` but the endpoint/url doesn't accept it.

Comment: is there something I can do to fix it?

Comment: You can only use the permissible operations on the url, so check what is allowed.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that the ```PUT``` method is supported?  Are you sure it isn't the ```POST``` method?

Comment: I read it in documentation of keycloak, The endpoint allow PUT according to documentations.